# Spacing between solar arrays

Tags: solar-panels, solar

I'm considering a solar farm in my backyard so I'm doing my initial research. Found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLvApPkV8sM). Here's a still from that video:

[image]

What's the point of that 12' gap between the arrays? Seems like a waste of space, but I'm sure there's a good reason for it, just want to know what it is.

Comment: heavy equipment access

Answer (score 4):

You don’t want one row of panels to place the next row  in shade.

You need to make a balanced choice about panel spacing... too close and you lose useful solar energy... too far and you have too much darn lawn to mow...

Comment: Also, when choosing your spacing, make sure you're looking at the winter sun angle (or summer if you're on the Upside Down).

Comment: And if you can make the spacing closer based on the sun's position in the sky etc , then do make sure you leave enough space for the mower or you get to cut it by hand... Perhaps you may enjoy the exercise... Saw a field with panels with larger spacing so the grass continued to grow well for the sheep... two sources of income from one field.

Comment: Why would you lose solar energy if one row is not in the shadow of another?

Comment: The whole point (of the space you are asking about) is to be sure that one row is not in the shadow of another.  That spacing needs to be adequate for low sun angles throughout the year and time of day, so if you are looking at a picture taken (evidently) near noon in summer and going "but the shadows are nowhere near the next row" you're not considering the actual problem realistically.

Comment: @Wynne yeah, the sun moves across the sky during the day, and the angle of the sun also changes significantly summer vs winter.  You can't just go by that photograph.  The array has to be laid out for the worst-case scenario.

Comment: it can also be a matter of heat; you want enough room to radiate and convect panel heat because hot cells are less efficient and don't last as long.